# How to create a reference for this for loop in python tkinter

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, reference

I need to reference my pic or else it will be put into the garbage. But I am finding it hard to put it in a list. Could someone show me how it's done?

```
 for i in range(lenlist1):
     b = Piclist[i]

     pic = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = b)


     d = (i*400) + 20

     canvas.create_image(1,d,image=pic, anchor = tkinter.NW)
```

Comment: It's the common way to go. But you have allready a list: `Piclist[i]` instead of hold only the filename put the result from `.PhotoImage(file = b)`.

Comment: ...or first create a new empty list and then `append(pic)` to it each iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: You add it to a list like you add anything to any list: `some_list.append(pic)`